# generating md5 checksum recursively and printing it in a text file with md5 , path and file size

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am learning bash shell script and i have given a task to recursively fetch for files in sub-directories and do md5 checksum and display the file size of it and output it as a text file line by line.

for example

- 662c1e24227048e50ae8e9c62b8a60da  yolo/happy/README.txt 20kb
- c2b1cd01a4595c134bca9502f35107de  apple/mango/bat/ball/apt.txt 30kb

for recursive i am using

find /home/kat/sam -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum > /home/kat/tempmd5new.txt

=======
which gives me output
662c1e24227048e50ae8e9c62b8a60da  yolo/happy/README.txt
c2b1cd01a4595c134bca9502f35107de  apple/mango/bat/ball/apt.txt

the main catch is I have to use find command .
thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, What is your current state? What has worked and what has not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This executes `md5sum` together with `wc -c`, which gets the number of bytes, saves the results into variables and concatenates it in a single echo print for every file:

```
find your/path -type f -exec bash -c 'md=$(md5sum "$0"); siz=$(wc -c <"$0"); echo ${md} ${siz}b' {} \;
```